# Error reading file that exists on Tomcat Deployment directory

Tags: tomcat

Im fairy new to java (as is our entire development team, long story short we used to be .Net and Domino developers then one day we were told to develop in java)

I have created a war file of our java development which I have deployed to our Tomcat server. The application deploys and runs ok but for some reason none of the validation messages are being displayed on the forms.

I have checked the log files in Tomcat and I am receiving the message `"g:\program files\apache software foundation\tomcat 7.0\webapps\griddemo\web-inf\classes\config\servicesvalidations.xml (the system cannot find the path specified)"` but when I check the directory the file does exist.

Any ideas why is it not being found?

Answer (score 0):

Is it a permissions issue? Make sure the server has read/write permissions for that particular file/directory.

Comment: Ive added the permission into the catalina.policy file (i think the code ive added is `grant codeBase "file:${catalina.home}/webapps/GRIDDEMO/WEB-INF/classes/config -" {
  permission java.io.FilePermission
         "${catalina.home}/webapps/GRIDDEMO/WEB-INF/classes/config", "read, write";
};`)

but still no validation messages are being displayed. It is however displaying navigation exception messages when trying to access a page which hasn’t been defined
@loeschg

Comment: Fixed the issue, it appears it couldn’t find the file because the tomcat installation path had spaces in i.e. \program files\apache software foundation\ I reinstalled tomcat and removed spaces and now the validations messages are all being triggered.